# Python write to Linux device using subprocess gives ValueError : embedded null byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, valueerror

On a Debian Linux system I have a Python script that prepares a string to be written out to a USB CDC device at /dev/ttyACM0.  This write occurs at the end of the script as follows...

```
USBpipe = open("/dev/ttyACM0", 'w')
shellCmd = subprocess.Popen(["echo", USBpacket], stdout = USBpipe)
USBpipe.close()
```

...where USBpacket is a string.  If I make this a pure string such as using `USBpacket = "test"` the code executes correctly and I've verified the data appears on the USB device.  However, during normal execution USBpacket gets bytes appended to it via the `chr()` function, and some of these may be zero.  When this happens I get this error running the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/gpstoPIC.py", line 247, in <module>
    shellCmd = subprocess.Popen(["echo", USBpacket], stdout = USBpipe)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1756, in _execute_child
    self.pid = _posixsubprocess.fork_exec(
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

I've tried a couple of solutions that haven't worked, such as doing `wb` instead of `w` on the open of `/dev/ttyACM0`, and using `bytes()` to convert from string to binary.  What is the correct way to write out this data?

Comment: Why are you using `echo` instead of `USBpipe.write(USBpacket)`? Wouldn't that be simpler?

Comment: It's a holdover from my research on looking up "how to send data to USB device Linux command line", `echo` was the only thing that I got to work, so when I was ready to write a script and not just test direct from the shell that's what I used.  However, after reading your comment I ditched using `subprocess` and used `write()` instead and it was just fine.  Since this was stated in a comment and not an official answer I picked the other post here as an answer even though it repeats what you said (along with some extraneous information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell in general, and `echo` in particular, can't cope with arbitrary binary input. Lucky thing then that Python can, and so you don't need a subprocess here at all.

```
with open("/dev/ttyACM0", "wb") as usb_pipe:
    usb_pipe.write(USBpacket)
```

If you really wanted to use a subprocess, try `cat` (but then that's really a [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)). Notice also how the `open` uses `"wb"` to open the filehandle in binary mode (plain `"w"` applies an encoding which again is not tolerant of or compatible with arbitrary binary data). And yes, if the data you want to send is really binary, `USBpacket` should indeed be a `bytes` object.

Finally, perhaps notice how I preferred `snake_case` over `CamelCase` for local scalar variable names; perhaps `USBpacket` should be renamed to adhere to PEP-8 recommendations, too.

Comment: Perhaps see also http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html for an exposition of the differences between strings and `bytes`. It covers Python 2, too, which is increasingly irrelevant, but apparently close to your mental model.